# Can ransomware encrypt data on protected devices by coming through unprotected devices?

Tags: windows, security, malware, anti-virus, anti-malware

We have about 8-10 Windows devices in our business. Some of them do not hold important data. Others store company accounting files, labels, inventory databases, etc. We would like to install a good anti-malware program on our computers, especially in prevention of ransomware.

Do we need this full protection on all devices, even if they do not store any significant data? (They would, of course, have standard, free, antivirus protection). Would malicious software, in case of infection, infect other computers, or compromise our network in some way, by coming in through computers that have less-complete protection?

Comment: Looking back, yes that was odd formatting. I didn't think much about it, was trying to get the right wording.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "anything"? Can the virus do more damage while connecting over the network then when the virus is directly on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a less important PC has access to files via the network (i.e. it can access files on a server or on a shared area of another PC) then those files could be damaged by a virus/malware running from that PC.

If you are trying to save money on licencing costs, I would at least put the anti-malware software on every PC that has access to the internet or is accessible to the public, or holds important data.

Which might potentially leave one or two utility PCs that perform specialist roles that are infrequently used - like if you had a PC that was hooked up to a scanner and that's all it was used for. At that point though, the difference between 8 licences is pretty similar to 10 licences so you might as well protect everything and be done with it. Especially when you consider the cost of data and IT time. For example, Malwarebytes business costs $50/licence/year. Whether you pay $400/year or $500/year it is pretty similar and the certainty of knowing that you haven't left an attack vector open is probably worth more than the $100/year saving.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, ransomware can do this - and in fact recent malware like "Wannacry" and a similar vulnerability for Unix filesharing can make use of flaws in SAMBA filesharing.

That said, I put to you you are asking the wrong question, because your model of security does not meet up with current best thinking - Security is all about layers (and least privilege).    When someone has access to a vulnerable system on your network - even if it is not an important one, they have already penetrated a major layer of the network - ie the firewall between the network and the outside world.  This means they have more visibility of your network and can launch attacks through the compromised system, which gives them a greater area to attack (eg taking advantage of known flaws on most implementations of DNSMASQ)

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can, the EternalBlue/Doublepulsar/Wannacry attack earlier in the year is the pure example of that.

One machine is compromised > SMBv1.0 vulnerability is exploited by eternalBlue > the Wannacry ransomware spread trough the network encrypting everything > hospitals and institutions lost crucial datas.